# 256 Char limitation on send email task in ssis

Tags: ssis

I have a send email task in my SSIS package which needs to send email to a couple of people. I have to send it to close to 30 people but due to the 256 char limitation on TO list in ssis I am unable to send email to more than 5 ppl.

"According to Microsoft:
The To, Cc, and Bcc lines are limited to 256 characters each in accordance with Internet standards."

How can fix this,One way I can think of is to put the send email task in a for each loop and send a separate email for each user but Is there a better way to handle this.

Comment: If you have a fixed number of people to send this to, you're better defining a an email group and sending to the group. That way when it changes you don't have to edit your package

Answer (score 1):

Use a Script Task to accomplish this task. In that manner, you can also have a well formatted HTML message.

Here is a link that best describes it -
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-scripting-task-examples/sending-an-html-mail-message-with-the-script-task